# How to display data from a model method

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Good evening community

I am new to programming and I have been working on a Django project to enhance my skills.

I would like to display data from a method model in my templates.

Here is the project's model,

```
class Company(models.Model):
    #Company data
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    outstanding_shares = models.IntegerField()
    share_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits= 5, decimal_places=2)
    revenue = models.IntegerField()
    expenses = models.IntegerField()
    total_assets = models.IntegerField()
    total_liabilities = models.IntegerField()
    current_assets = models.IntegerField()
    current_liabilities = models.IntegerField()
    operating_cashflows = models.IntegerField()
    capex = models.IntegerField()
    
    #Date of creation
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)    
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name

    #Company methods
        
    def net_income(self):        
        return self.revenue - self.expenses
```

Here is the Views file,

```
def tools(request):
    submitted = False
    form = CompanyForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST)
        form = CompanyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()        
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/simple_investing/tools?submitted=True')

    else:
        form = CompanyForm        
        if 'submitted' in request.GET:
            submitted = True
        context = {'form': form, 'submitted': submitted}    
        return render(request, 'simple_investing/tools.htm', context)
```

Here is the forms file,

```
class CompanyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('company_name', 'outstanding_shares', 'share_price', 'revenue', 'expenses', 'total_assets','total_liabilities', 'current_assets','current_liabilities', 'operating_cashflows', 'capex')
        widgets = {
            'company_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Company name'}),
            'outstanding_shares': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Shares outstanding'}),
            'share_price' :forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Share price'}),
            'revenue' :forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Revenue'}),
            'expenses' :forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Expenses'}),
            'total_assets' :forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Total Assets'}),
            'total_liabilities' :forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Total Liabilities'}),
            'current_assets' :forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Current Assets'}),
            'current_liabilities' :forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Current Liabilities'}),
            'operating_cashflows' :forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Operating Cashflows'}),
            'capex' :forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Capital Expenditure'}),
            
        }
```

Here is the templates file,

```
<body>
{% if submitted %}
    Your company was submitted successfully. Hereunder is your company's net income:
    {{% Company.net_income %}}
{% else %}

<p>In this section, we will analyze the fundamentals of a company of your choice. The goal is to assess if the <strong><i>stock market</i></strong> is offering us an investment opportunity. </p>
<p>Let's start by entering the data of the company that you are interested in: </p>
    
<div class="row g-3">                  
    <form action ="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button> 
        
    </form>
```

I get the following error:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '% Company.net_income %' from '% Company.net_income %'
```

Any ideas as to how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In templates file

- Remove: `{{% Company.net_income %}}`
- Try this: `{{ Company.net_income }}`

Comment: That did not work, any other suggestions?